# Displaying the name and data type of every column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe

I am working on a Database Management Systems assignment and have been unable to find a way to display the name and datatype of every column in a specific table. I don't know if this is needed but here is the link to the schema I am using for this assignment.

http://mym.cdn.laureate-media.com/2dett4d/Walden/ITEC/ITEC2060/documents/Schema.sql

The employee table is what I am trying to display from.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to create a program that displays the database name and type of each column? Or are you just using a command line tool such as SQLPLUS and want to see that information?

Comment: I'm using a Run SQL Command Line.
For this assignment I have a provided schema and a list of tasks to go through all related to displaying things. 
I don't know if this helps but for the actual submission I create a word doc with a copy of my queries and a screen shot of the output.

Comment: Then this question is probably more appropriate for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ which is for Database Administrators. This site is programming specific.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about the misplaced question.

Comment: The question is not misplaced... don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

To list all columns for a specific table:

```
select column_name, data_type
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
```

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#I1020277

If you are using SQL*Plus you can simply run

```
desc EMPLOYEES
```

instead.

Most other SQL clients have a similar feature.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe this is what I was intended to to.